# Implement an interface without errors

Tags: interface, compiler-errors, asp.net-mvc-5, lazy-loading

I have written an interface for a class as follows:

```
public interface IGenericMultipleRepository
{
    Lazy<IGenericRepository<Address>> addresses { get; set; }
    Lazy<IGenericRepository<Asset>> assets { get; set; }
}
```

I am implementing this interface as follows:

```
public class GenericMultipleRepository : IGenericMultipleRepository
```

Here are the values that I have implemented:

```
public Lazy<IGenericRepository<Address>> addresses;
public Lazy<IGenericRepository<Asset>> assets;
```

Here are the errors that I am getting:

> 'CanFindLocation.Repositories.GenericMultipleRepository' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'CanFindLocation.Interfaces.IGenericMultipleRepository.assets'
>
> 'CanFindLocation.Repositories.GenericMultipleRepository' does not
>   implement interface member
>   'CanFindLocation.Interfaces.IGenericMultipleRepository.addresses'

How can I implement the interface `IGenericMultipleRepository` without any errors.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only reason I can see is since you are implementing an interface that you forgot to put

```
Lazy<IGenericRepository<Address>> addresses { get; set; }
Lazy<IGenericRepository<Asset>> assets { get; set; }
```

inside your `GenericMultipleRepository` class definition

Also, your 
    `public Lazy<IGenericRepository<Address>> addresses;` only creates a variable, which doesn`t match with what the compiler is expecting.

Your compiler is expecting a Property not variables.